# Having issue removing a file in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to remove a file after checking some thing in that. I'm capturing the whole path into a variable and passing it to `Remove-Item` command and I'm getting below error:

```
Remove-Item : An object at the specified path E:\Import\IRIS_Import\working\RP
LS_BAI_20120719092600450-20120719093206.csv    does not exist.

At E:\Import\IRIS_Import\FIX_IRIS_49_FILES_kr.ps1:53 char:13
+  Remove-Item <<<<  $file
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], PSArgumentEx 
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveIte 
   mCommand
```

Not sure why Powershell is complaining about file not being there even I can see the file there physically. Any ideas please?

Comment: Do `Test-Path 'E:\Import\IRIS_Import\working\RP LS_BAI_20120719092600450-20120719093206.csv'`

Answer (score 1):

I faced this exact same issue when I ran an Azure powershell webjob. I followed the [answer in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25607109/5435132) in addition's to justinf's answer in this thread and modified my `remove-item` command as below.

```
remove-item filesystem::\\uncpath\folder
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the file had an - in the file name and powershell does not like this it would seem.

This code worked for me. If it does not work for you post more of your code up and I will take a look.

```
$test = "c:\test\LS_BAI_20120719092600450-20120719093206.csv"

Remove-Item -LiteralPath $test
```