# Remove-Item doesn't work, Delete does

Tags: windows, powershell

Does anyone have any idea why `Remove-Item` would fail while `Delete` works?

---

In below script, I get a list of files I'd like to delete.
Using `Remove-Item` I get following error message:

> VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target
>   "\\UncPath\Folder\test.rtf".   Remove-Item : Cannot remove item
>   \\UncPath\Folder\test.rtf: Access to the path is denied.

but using `Delete` is deleting those files as we speak.

**Script**

```
$files = gci \\UncPath\Folder| ?{ $_.LastWriteTime -le (Get-Date).addDays(-28) }

# This doesn't work
$files | Remove-Item -force -verbose

# But this does
$files | % { $_.Delete() }
```

Comment: that worked on my PSV4 box. What version are you running ? did you try to specify the full path : `$files = gci \\UncPath\Folder| ?{ $_.LastWriteTime -le (Get-Date).addDays(-28) |select fullname}`

Comment: `$PSVersionTable` returns 4.0 for `PSVersion`. Appending the `select fullname`, I now get an errormessage like such `Remove-Item : Cannot find path '\\UncPath\Folder\@{FullName=\UncPath\Folder\test.RTF}' because it does not exist.`.

Comment: `$files[0]` returns `\\UncPath\Folder\test.RTF`

Comment: sorry it should be `$files.fullname |remove-item -whatif  `

Comment: `$files.fullname | Remove-Item -whatif` returns `What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "\\UncPath\Folder\test.rtf".`

Comment: so remove -whatif to check if the files are deleted

Comment: That's working?! But why? Please do post as an answer so I can upvote :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60395/discussion-between-kayasax-and-lieven-keersmaekers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can finally repro this and IMO it appears to be a bug.  The repro is to have an open share like C$ but to set Deny Modify perms for the user on the file.  When I do that, I observe this:

```
PS> gci '\\Keith-PC\C$\Users\Keith\foo.txt' | ri -for
ri : Cannot remove item \\Keith-PC\C$\Users\Keith\foo.txt: Access to the path is denied.
At line:1 char:43
+ gci '\\Keith-PC\C$\Users\Keith\foo.txt' | ri -for
+                                           ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (\\Keith-PC\C$\Users\Keith\foo.txt:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], ArgumentExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

PS> gci '\\Keith-PC\C$\Users\Keith\foo.txt' | %{$_.Delete()} # <== this works!
```

I also observe that removing the `-Force` parameter deletes the file without error as well. The deny perms still allow me to delete the file from Windows Explorer so that leads me to believe that the file should delete.  So what is up with using the `-Force` parameter?  When I delve into the ErrorRecord I see this:

```
Message        : Access to the path is denied.
ParamName      :
Data           : {}
InnerException :
TargetSite     : Void set_Attributes(System.IO.FileAttributes)
StackTrace     :    at System.IO.FileSystemInfo.set_Attributes(FileAttributes value)
                    at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemProvider.RemoveFileSystemItem(FileSystemInfo
                 fileSystemInfo, Boolean force)
```

It seems that the `-Force` parameter is trying to set (more likely *reset*) attributes and the permissions on the file don't allow it e.g.:

```
PS> gci '\\Keith-PC\C$\Users\Keith\foo.txt' | %{$_.Attributes = 'Normal'}
Exception setting "Attributes": "Access to the path is denied."
At line:1 char:45
+ gci '\\Keith-PC\C$\Users\Keith\foo.txt' | %{$_.Attributes = 'Normal'}
+                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
```

So it seems to me that PowerShell should first try as if the `-Force` weren't present and if that fails, then try resetting attributes.

Comment: That makes sense. Kayasax solved my immediate problem *(tx again)* but future visitors benefit more from this being the accepted answer. I have switched the accepted answer.

Comment: I submitted this a defect.  If you agree, please vote on it: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedbackdetail/view/962980/remove-item-force-fails-when-remove-item-succeeds-on-the-same-file

Comment: This appears to still be a bug in Powershell v5.1.17134.48. Microsoft Connect has been retired, so Keith's defect report link is broken. Looks like they've moved to Uservoice. I found the report here:
https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/11088240-remove-item-force-fails-when-remove-item-succeeds
Seems they weren't able to migrate votes from connect to uservoice, so go vote on it, there's only 1 vote!

Comment: And now uservoice is also apparently not being used either.

Answer (score 9):

powershell may act strange with UNC path, I think it prepends the UNC Path with the current provider you can verify this with :

```
cd c:
test-path \\127.0.0.1\c$
```

> returns TRUE

```
cd HKCU:
test-path \\127.0.0.1\c$
```

> returns FALSE

when specifying the fullpath we're telling powershell to use the **filesystem provider**, that solves the problem. you could also specify the provider like `remove-item filesystem::\\uncpath\folder`

Comment: Hmm, still not sure this explains what the OP is seeing - which I can't replicate.  An error of "access denied" means `$files | ri` is finding the file but can't delete due to perms.  I see this when I use a readonly share. If I use an admin share (C$) like you do above, then the remove-item succeeds.  In fact, what is passed to Remote-Item's LiteralPath parameter in the pipeline is the full provider path `PSPath` (LiteralPath has an alias PSPath - hence the pipeline binding).  What you demonstrate above is that a non-drive qualified path `\\\` is problematic as a parameter.  :-)

Comment: @KeithHill - fyi, you might be right. Additional testing shows that by just removing the `-force` parameter, my initial script also works.

Comment: @KeithHill so what would explain that the other method (delete()) succeed ? It cant be a permission problem. Plus I gave an example using c$ but the problem is the same using a non admin share.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers see my answer to this for an explanation.