# Remove-Item : Cannot find path '\\footfs32\Builds\TestBuildTest\foo_3.3.17009.3.zip ' because it does not exist

Tags: powershell

I am trying to remove all files and folders in a specific network path location (the tfs build drop folder of one of my builds).

In my post-build script I tried the following lines: (with same results)

```
$Destination = '\\footfs32\Builds\TestBuildTest'
Get-ChildItem -Path $Destination -Recurse | Remove-Item -force -recurse

Remove-Item \\footfs32\Builds\TestBuildTest -Force -Recurse

Remove-Item "\\footfs32\Builds\TestBuildTest\*" -Force -Recurse 

Remove-Item -LiteralPath "\\footfs32\Builds\TestBuildTest\*" -Force -Recurse
```

All included folders are being removed, but when it tries to remove the files in the dir, the following error pops ups:

> Remove-Item : Cannot find path
>   '\abctfs32\Builds\TestBuildTest\foo_3.3.17009.3.zip ' because it does
>   not exist.'

Why is this error popping up on files only, while all folders are deleted correctly? This doesn't make any sense to me. And how do I fix it?

Comment: may be you dont have permission for remove this file

Comment: Unfortunately all folders and files were created by the same user (the build server service account) during the previous builds.

Comment: After the build and ps script, could you see those files in the physically build drop folder ?

Comment: How did you create the zip file with a space in it?

Comment: This might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25606481/2157640

Answer (score 0):

According to the error info.Very likely the file had been deleted in your build process.

Some events triggered during your build process, and that file had been deleted. When running the powershell script, those files couldn't be found. The `Remove-item`  command Can not delete a file twice.

Please double check your build definition, build process and drop folder.

Comment: It is not deleted. I can still see it when navigating into the directory. Further more its a single statement. I doubt it would be deleted right between the directory deletion and the file deletion. Why would the Remove-Item find those files in the first place then, when my build process deletes those files before that statement was executed.

Comment: Did you mean only the files with ".zip " can not be deleted. Or all files except folders can't be deleted. Also try to manually delete those files to make sure if you have  appropriate permissions and the files are not locked by any other process.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following command:

```
Remove-Item -Path "\\footfs32\Builds\TestBuildTest\*.*" -Force -Recurse
```

Comment: you can also use the "-whatif" parameter to see what will happen if you execute the command without actually deleting anything.

Comment: Oh, I just figured out, that my files have a space behind the zip-Extension.... like ".zip ". Can I delete files with a space at last place?

Comment: I don't think it's a problem... did you try the command above ?